# Plans for drive.appdata scope in android google drive API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I want to use files in the special application data folder in new android application im developing (aka [drive.appdata](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/appdata) scope).

You guys at google did an excelent job in the new Google Drive Android API which is bundled with the Google Play Services 4.2.

But I found out that its not possible to use the appdata folder in the Android API, because there is only the scope drive.file. 
Now I have to use the generic java/web api in android for this.

There are plans to implement the drive.appdata scope in the android API ? When ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question might be out of scope for this site.  This is not Google.

Comment: SO is the only place where Google provides any support for its APIs

Comment: Yes, google uses the stackoverflow to support google drive sdk, please check out https://developers.google.com/drive/support

Comment: Similar question had been asked : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807602/migration-strategy-for-google-drive-android-api-from-google-api-java-client-go (Unfortunately, no answer yet...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are being added recently in Google Play Services 4.3

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/03/google-play-services-43.html

> Note: The Google Drive Android API currently only supports drive.file
>   and drive.appdata authorization scopes. If your application requires
>   additional permissions or features not yet available in the Drive
>   Android API, you must use the Google APIs Java Client.

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_the_google_drive_android_api

Comment: Good! They did drive.appdata on native Android API. Plus, we have the new features "pinning" and "change notifications". Excellent! Thanx Cheok