# Authorizing my application to use an Existing Folder

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Using the Android Drive API, when trying to connect using:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

getGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

I get the select an account screen and after selecting an account, I see this:

[image]

> View and manage Google Drive files that you have opened or created
>   with this app

What if I what to access files created by other apps?

Is there a way for my application to ask for authorization of a specific folder?

Answer (score 5):

[**Google Play Services client library**](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html) provides an Android developer with APIs for seamless integration with the individual Google services.

The library also let your apps offers a consistent user interface to obtain authorization from users to access these services with their credentials.

**Access to Google Drive Service**

Google Play services client library ships with [**Google Drive Android API**](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) that provides access to the Google Drive service.

However, Google Drive Android API currently offers only *drive.file* and *drive.appfolder* [authorization scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes) which are limited in a way if your app needs access to all the contents on the user's drive.

To provide  drive scope, you will need to use REST APIs offered by [**Drive API Client Library for Java**](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2). This library has a dependency on [**Google APIs Client Library for Java**](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/) that offers generated client libs for access to individual Google services using REST APIs from any application (web, installed or Android)

[Download the Drive API v2 Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/drive/v2/java). The libs folder contains all the globally-applicable dependencies (Google APIs Client Library for Java) you might need across all application types (web, installed, or Android application).

For Android, you will need the following jars (as described in drive/readme.html) to sort out the dependencies

```
google-api-services-drive-v2-rev143-1.19.0.jar
google-api-client-1.19.0.jar
google-api-client-android-1.19.0.jar
google-http-client-1.19.0.jar
google-http-client-android-1.19.0.jar
google-http-client-gson-1.19.0.jar
google-oauth-client-1.19.0.jar
gson-2.1.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
```

**Authorization**

Before accessing Google Drive (or any other Google) service, you need to authorize your application (using OAuth 2.0)

1. For applications using *Google Play Services client library*, this will be handled by [**GoogleApiClient**](http://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html).
2. However, if the service/Google API you want to use is not included in the *Google Play services library*, you can connect using the appropriate REST API to manually make requests or using a client library provided by the service provider, but you must obtain an OAuth 2.0 token.

For *drive* scope, you need to use *Google APIs Client Library for Java* and the generated client libraries (drive v2, in our case). To obtain an authorization token, you can either -

- directly use the [OAuth 2.0](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2) library from *Google APIs Client Library for Java* (not preferred for android)
- or leverage the authorization portion of the Google Play services library using [**GoogleAuthUtil**](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html) and AccountPicker. [Read Authorizing with Google for REST APIs](http://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html). (GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() caches and manages token expiry and refresh itself. However, in case of network errors/server load, you might need to use an exponential back-off algorithm before retrying for the token so to not flood the server with requests. Refer 3)
- or use the [**GoogleAccountCredential**](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.19.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GoogleAccountCredential.html) defined in google-api-client-android-1.19.0.jar that comes with *Google APIs Client Library for Java*. The package offers Utilities based on [Google Play services](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/) and [*GoogleAccountCredential is just a wrapper*](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-preview-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/android/GoogleAccountCredential.java?repo=samples&r=1b9b4ba72aa7f22496918edd40a55c3002f4a6cf) around *GoogleAuthUtil* and *AccountPicker*.  This would allow you to use the same consistent authorization flow and the standard account picker UI that comes with Google Play services client library while delegating the token management and using an exponential back-off strategy (as noted above) to GoogleAccountCredential. Refer [1](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html) for an example.

Note that with the last two approaches, you are using both *Google Play services client libraries* (for **authorization**) and *Google APIs Client Library for Java* along with *Drive API v2 Client Library for Java* (for **access** to Google Drive service with *drive* authentication scope).

**Package references**

- [Google Play Services client library](https://developer.android.com/reference/gms-packages.html)
- [Drive API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2)
- [Google API Client Library for Java 1.19.0](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.19.0/index.html)

Also checkout -

1. http://www.techsfo.com/blog/2014/03/android-preparing-to-access-google-drive-with-an-app-part-1/
2. http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Using-Google-APIs
3. [Google Play services and OAuth Identity Tools](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012_09_01_archive.html)

This answer also posted at my blog [here](http://stackedonheap.wordpress.com/2014/09/16/creating-android-apps-to-interact-with-google-drive/).

Comment: This is the most helpful reply ! I am writing a Google Drive File Browser, and the tutorial at:

Answer (score 4):

Google Drive Android API only support two scopes:

drive.file: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file)
Per-file access to files created or opened by the app

drive.appdata (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata)
Allows access to the Application Data folder

You need to use the Google Drive web service (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) and your application must use the Google APIs Client Library for Java. (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client)

The scope for full access: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"

```
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE); 
credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName); 
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the API provided by Google Play Services. It doesn't support `DRIVE` scope. Without `DRIVE` scope, you don't have enough privilege to access files created by other apps.

You may use **DriveScopes.DRIVE**, this is what I'm doing in my app. My android app needs to exchange data with my legacy desktop app.

You need to use API from Java Jar library. https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-java A lot of JAR files need to be included, which will increase your final APK size. But, with the help of ProGuard, the size of APK is still manageable.

However, I foresee Google will soon enforce developers to use only Google Play Services, which is part of their business strategy. So, you need to have some sort of backup plan, in case that happens.

For further information, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807602/migration-strategy-for-google-drive-android-api-from-google-api-java-client-go and [Plans for drive.appdata scope in android google drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185941/plans-for-drive-appdata-scope-in-android-google-drive-api)

Answer (score 0):

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Drive.API)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
```

I think you missed the addScope, I never worked with it myself but this is what i could find missing, when looking at the documentation.
[documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth)

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonlyAllows apps read-only access to the list of Drive apps a user has installed. acoording the documentation page https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes

Comment: I have added the scope. You can check code in the question.